# Does docker cache files/directories? If so, is it possible to force it to refresh its cache?

Tags: docker, caching

Anyone know if Docker somehow caches files/file systems?  And if it does, is there a way to suppress that or force it to regenerate/refresh the cache.  I am editing my files outside my docker image, but the directory inside the docker image doesn't seem to include them in it. However, outside the docker image the "same" directory does include the files.  The only thing that makes sense to me is that docker has an internal "copy" of the directory and isn't going to the disk, so it sees an outdated copy of the directory before the file was added.

Details:
I keep my "work" files in a directory on a separate partition (/Volumes/emacs) on my MacBook, i.e.:

```
/Volumes/emacs/datapelago
```

I do my editing in emacs on the MacBook, but not in the docker container.  I have a link to that directory called:

```
/projects
```

And I might edit or create a file called:

```
/projects/nuc-440/qflow/ToAttribute.java
```

In the meantime I have a docker container I created this way:

```
docker container create -p 8080:8080 -v /Volumes/emacs/datapelago:/projects -v /Users/christopherfclark:/Users/cfclark --name nuc-440 gradle:7.4.2-jdk17 tail -f /dev/null
```

I keep a shell running in that container:

```
docker container exec -it nuc-440 /bin/bash
cd /projects/nuc-440
```

And after making changes I run the build/test sequence:

```
gradle clean;gradle build;gradle test
```

However, recently I have noticed that when I make changes, add files, they don't always get reflected inside the docker container, which of course can cause the build to fail or the test not to pass etc.

Thus, this question.

I'd rather not have to start/stop the container each time and instead just keep it running and tell it to "refetch" the projects/nuc-440 directory and its children.

---

I restarted the docker container and it is now "tracking" file changes again.  That is I can make changes in MacOS and they are reflected inside docker with no additional steps.  I don't seem to have to continually restart it.  It must have gotten into a "wierd" state.  However, I don't have any useful details beyond that.   Sorry.

Comment: Did you rebuild your image?  That's normally a required step, after you've modified your code on the host and run unit tests there.

Comment: I have to rebuild my image every time?   I build the app inside the docker container and run the unit tests there.  The files aren't part of the "image" just a mounted drive.  So, do I have to stop/start the container and remount the drive.

Comment: Hi, intel your file is in your mount directory?

Comment: I am having the same issue. I am using a container to run my python app, but editing my files outside the container and bind-mounting the directory into the container when running. Lately it seems docker is somehow caching the bind-mounted directories and I can't seem to disable that caching.